# Doubts regarding arc length of a circle/units

Tags: analysis, circles, unit-of-measure

how is this dimensionally correct?

[image]

why does the degrees or if expressed in radians,disappear i.e. why does length of an arc have unit meters and not radian meter/ degree meter?
Can someone explain it with other units?

Comment: sure ima write it properly. Thanks btw

Comment: Judging merely from the last line, the error is that the denominator ought to be $180^\circ$ instead of merely $180.$ Refer to point 3 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4289650/21813).