# Is a degree measurement a real number?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analysis

I feel that a radian measurement is a real number because we use it widely in calculus and the evaluation of limits of real and complex functions; but I've never heard, for example, someone consider $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$ when $x$ is in degrees.

Is an angle in degrees not a mathematical quantity, but a physical quantity?

Is a degree measurement a real number?

Comment: Not following.  It's just a unit.  If you believe radians exist, then degrees are just a rescaling of that notion.  Specifically, $1$ degree is $\frac  {180}{\pi}$ radians.

Comment: "I know that degree is a mathematical constant which it is a key number whose value is fixed by an unambiguous definition" is not at all clear.   Also, how do you distinguish "mathematical quantity" and "physical quantity"?

Comment: I think the question is asking: is a degree a unitless quantity [like a radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Dimensional_analysis)? I would think, yes: $1^\circ = 180/\pi \operatorname{rad} = 180/\pi$.  Others may disagree.

Comment: Distinguishing between dimensionless real numbers, and a dimensioned number (i.e. $37$ degrees, or $37^\circ$) and confusion around the term radian has been discussed often at mathSE.  See, for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3884616/how-to-calculate-sin37-with-a-taylor-approximation/3884686?r=SearchResults&s=2|22.5701#3884686).

Comment: Typos. One degree is $\pi/180$ radians.

Comment: You appear to be saying that you do not know what the phrase "real number" means in mathematcs.

Comment: If you take the view that radian angle measure is "unitless", then ° is just a special symbol for $\frac{\pi}{180}$ in the same way that % is a special symbol for $\frac{1}{100}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. $180^\circ,\, π\text{ rad},\, 7\text{ cm}$ are all physical
   quantities, each having both a numerical value *and* a unit.

   An angle can be construed as a *ratio of lengths*: its **number
   of degrees** is $$\frac{180}\pi\times\frac{\text{length of the arc
   that subtends the angle at a circle's centre}}{\text{radius of the
   circle}}.$$ Being a measure of some quotient of lengths $\left(\frac{\textrm m}{\textrm m}=1\right),$ **an angle is a** [**dimensionless quantity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity#Ratios,_proportions,_and_angles). To be clear though, an angle *does* have units: it is measured/specified in radians, degrees, gradians, etc.
2. It's instructive to understand the two standard versions of each
   trigonometric function as being in fact **two different
   functions**: one accepts an input with unit $^{\circ}$, the other
   accepts a unitless input (the $\textrm{rad}$ having been divided out
   so that the domain really is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C};$ [each element of the former *corresponds* to but isn't an angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4505941/21813)), and both returning the
   same output for equivalent inputs. (To distinguish between them, some authors call the latter the *natural* trigonometric functions.)

   - $\sin(\pi)\neq\sin(180)=\sin(233^{\circ}).$
   - The Taylor series $\displaystyle\sin(x)=x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \ldots$ wouldn't be consistent if $x$ carries any unit.
   - Only the unitless version of sine can be recursively composed $$\sin\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right) = \sin\left(\frac{180^{\circ}}{\pi}\sin\left(45^{\circ}\right)\right),$$ whereas $$\sin\left(\sin(45^{\circ})\right)$$ is not meaningful.
   - $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin(x^{\circ})=\frac{\pi}{180}\cos(x^{\circ});$$ the derivative of $\sin(x^{\circ})$ at $x{=}60\:$ is $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{360},$ *not* $\displaystyle\frac12.$
3. Similarly, in the arc length formula $s=r\theta,$ the subtended
   angle is $\theta\textrm{ rad},$ *not* $\theta.$

   - $“s=r(\pi)”$ and $“s=r(\pi\text{ rad})”$ are not synonymous; the latter is as incoherent as $“s=r(180^{\circ})”.$
4. The above points illustrate that unlike degree and gradian, radian is *the* natural angular measure. So much so that in mathematics, the unit "$\textrm{rad}$" is generally dropped whenever the context is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, a unit of measurement (which doesn't measure quantity) can't be a real number. 
However, the measurements with that unit can be a real number (2$\pi$ radians, 54 degrees, 0.23 revolutions, ...)

In your question, you have stated that "radian" should be a real number because *we use it widely in calculus*. However, the example you gave ($\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} $) doesn't imply that a radian is a real number (specifically because sin x is a real number, and sin is defined in radians). You might find other equations in calculus or trig that involve radians, but they always fall into one of these categories:

- those equations directly use radians (an oversimplified example can be $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$), which returns an answer in (an unit used to measure angles). There aren't any connections between the radian (or any other units) and real numbers here.

  those equations involve radians, but actually returns real numbers. In that case, there must be a function that takes in an angle measurement and returns a real number (take the trig functions for example) (you won't find any equations that doesn't involve those functions). Which, again, doesn't make any connections between radians and real numbers.

Degrees are also an unit that we use to measure angles (1 degree = $\frac{\pi}{180}$ radians). Therefore, we can have valid equations (not just in calculus but in other fields as well) using degrees.

we just need to multiply the measurement in degrees with $\frac{180}{\pi}$

In conclusion, radians (and degrees) are just units that we use to measure angles (in the same way that a meter is used to measure lengths or a gram is used to measure mass), and they aren't equivalent to any real numbers (in the same way that you can't convert a meter to kilograms).

(sorry if this answer is confusing - this is my first answer ever)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).